# Insertion of chinese character into oracle sql database

Tags: sql

I need to insert and retrieve Chinese character from oracle sql databases.pls provide example with explanation.Thanksss

Comment: Please try for yourself and ask, when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Column type should be of type `NVARCHAR` to store chinese characters. And when inserting use character `N` in following `N'some text'`

Comment: i am able to insert into but i am facing problem while retrieving the value,when i am passing select query its showing ¿¿¿